# Sorting an array of hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have an array of hashes which look like:

```
ward = {id: id, name: record["Externalization"], mnemonic: record["Mnemonic"],
   seqno: record["SeqNo"]}
```

All fields are strings.

Now I want to sort them first on seqno and then on name. seqno can be nil (if seqno is nil, then this ward must come after the ones having a seqno).

What I have so far is:

```
wardList.sort! do |a,b| 
  return (a[:name] <=> b[:name]) if (a[:seqno].nil? && b[:seqno].nil?) 
  return -1 if a[:seqno].nil?
  return 1 if b[:seqno].nil?
  (a[:seqno] <=> b[:seqno]).nonzero? ||
    (a[:name] <=> b[:name])
end
```

But this gives me the error: **can't convert Symbol into Integer**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, *normalize your data*, you can't work with integers as strings here:

```
wardList = wardList.map { |x| x.merge({:id    => x[:id].to_i, 
                                       :seqno => x[:seqno].try(:to_i) }) }
```

Then you can use `sort_by`, which supports lexicographical sorting:

```
wardList.sort_by! { |x| [x[:seqno] || Float::INFINITY, x[:name]] }
```

Example:

```
irb(main):034:0> a = [{:seqno=>5, :name=>"xsd"}, 
                      {:seqno=>nil, :name=>"foo"}, 
                      {:seqno=>nil, :name=>"bar"}, 
                      {:seqno=>1, :name=>"meh"}]
irb(main):033:0> a.sort_by { |x| [x[:seqno] || Float::INFINITY, x[:name]] }
=> [{:seqno=>1, :name=>"meh"},
    {:seqno=>5, :name=>"xsd"},
    {:seqno=>nil, :name=>"bar"},
    {:seqno=>nil, :name=>"foo"}]
```

Comment: Yes, but what if a[:seqno] is nil?

Comment: I'm getting the error no implicit conversion from nil to integer.

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking about something like that, but it seems like a nasty workaround...

Comment: @Lieven: Rather seems like you're original code is a nasty workaround... But I guess the real problem is the *requirements* you have, not the code. That specification just can't be expressed in a simple way because of "seqno can be nil". I guess you choose the wrong representation of your data right from the beginning, now you have to live with the consequences ;)

Comment: @Lieven, why nasty? how do you compare a number with `nil`? it's only natural to set a default value to cover this case.

Comment: @Lieven: You can always normalize the data by assigning meaningful sequence numbers as a one-time translation between "legacy" and "clean, current code".

Comment: Well, you can give a sequence number of unkown/nil. So how would you resolve this? I could give a number like 999999 to it, but that's not a good solution. What about solution of PinnyM (other answer).

Comment: @Lieven: *Why* would you allow sequence number of nil? That doesn't seem to make any sense to me. Why don't you automatically create an ID if none is given (like, assign the smallest number not yet existing). What do you mean, "What about solution of PinnyM"? Of course there are several ways to do it, I only added this answer because his solution didn't work before the edit.

Comment: Well, the sequence number is more like an order id. If none is assigned, it has to come at the end of the list.

Comment: @Lieven: So now you have two one-line solutions to solve this task perfectly simple and elegant. Congratulations.

Comment: this solution puts the elements with a seqno of nil at the top, either use +Float::INFINITY or try my solution. i like the elegance of @NiklasB.'s solution though!

Comment: Btw, this gives me an error: no implicit conversion from nil to integer

Comment: @Lieven: That's hard to believe, there are no `nil`s involved any longer. Can you provide a minimal array that shows the problem?

Comment: DEBUG Ward: {:id=>"50801", :name=>"name", :mnemonic=>"mn", :seqno=>nil}
DEBUG Ward: {:id=>"31", :name=>"name", :mnemonic=>"mn", :seqno=>nil}
DEBUG Ward: {:id=>"136672", :name=>"name", :mnemonic=>"mn", :seqno=>"10"}
DEBUG Ward: {:id=>"33", :name=>"name", :mnemonic=>"mn", :seqno=>"30"}
DEBUG Ward: {:id=>"26", :name=>"name", :mnemonic=>"mn", :seqno=>nil}
DEBUG Ward: {:id=>"29", :name=>"name", :mnemonic=>"B4", :seqno=>nil}

ERROR TypeError: no implicit conversion from nil to integer.

Comment: If you really want to know, the data comes from Progress/OpenEdge application, through a Java proxy bridge, to Jruby on Rails.

Comment: @Lieven: *just convert them*. You know that integers as strings are sorted lexicographically, so `"9" > "100"`? Also, your error message doesn't fit to the data, it should be more like `ArgumentError: comparison of Array with Array failed` because INFINITY can't be compared to a string

Comment: Mmm, good point there, will have to convert them. Problem is that if I convert them to integer, nil becomes 0...

Comment: @Lieven: You seem to be lacking some basic understanding of the tools you are working with. Check my answer for an example of how to transform the data properly.

Comment: $ irb
irb(main):001:0> a = nil
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> a.to_i
=> 0
irb(main):003:0>

Comment: @Leven: `a = nil; a && a.to_i` => `nil` or even `a.try(:to_i)`.

Comment: @Nilas B. Can you point me to a resource explaining the a && a.to_i? Haven't found that in the basic tutorials/books I've read.

Comment: The and and && operators evaluate their first operand. If false, the expression returns false; otherwise, the expression returns the value of the second operand. So nil is false?

Comment: @Lieven: Exactly the values `false` and `nil` are considered boolean false in Ruby. So with the first operand being `nil`, the second operand is not even evaluated. By the way, the expression doesn't return `false`, it returns the first falsy value (`nil` in this case).

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
sorted = wardList.sort_by{|a| [a[:seqno] ? 0 : 1, a[:seqno], a[:name]] }
```

or for some rubies (e.g. 1.8.7):

```
sorted = wardList.sort_by{|a| [a[:seqno] ? 0 : 1, a[:seqno] || 0, a[:name]] }
```

Comment: Edited, that should include what you need

Comment: sorts first on `nil?` status of `:seqno` (as string - 'false' will always precede 'true'), then on `:seqno`, then on `:name`

Comment: Great solution. But how come it doesn't crash on a[:seqno] when it's nil?

Comment: sort_by uses tuple comparison, as opposed to standard sort comparison.  Apparently tuples are allowed to contain nil (but not `true` or `false`), although I'm not sure myself how the comparison implementation actually does this.  `nil` will normally precede non-nil, which is why we need to first sort on nil status

Comment: @Pinny: Lists (not tuples) are compared component-wise, in [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). You can't compare booleans (they don't define the `<` operator), so you can't use those as a list components. You also can't compare `nil` to any non-nil value. Conversion to strings seems a bit overkill here, I'd simply go with `a[:seqno] ? 1 : 0` (which should be a lot faster).

Comment: wardList.sort_by!{|a| [a[:seqno] ? 1 : 0, a[:seqno], a[:name]] }

Comment: @Lieven, no: `sort_by {|x| [x[:seqno] ? 1 : 0, x[:seqno], x[:name]] }`

Comment: Ok, idd, was too late to change it. You're too fast.

Comment: @Pinny: The `.nil?` is not needed. The `|| 0` should also not be needed.

Comment: @NiklasB. thanks for all the optimization tips.  The `|| 0` is needed as I just noticed that this will fail without it if there are multiple nils in the list. So my theory about nils being sortable in tuples was wrong (as you had pointed out earlier), but using `|| 0` will let it pass.

Comment: @PinnyM: It should *not* be needed, did you try it?

Comment: I tried wardList.sort_by!{|a| [a[:seqno] ? 0 : 1, a[:seqno], a[:name]] } with multiple nils and it works.

Comment: Oh, by the way, looking back at the question it should really be `a[:seqno] ? 0 : 1`

Comment: Yes I did, and got `undefined method '<=>' for nil:NilClass`.  This only happens if more than one nil exists (or the secondary sort will not be attempted for `nil`)

Comment: Ah, I see, you're probably using Ruby 1.8. This version is a bit ancient, Ruby 1.9 changed the semantics here.

Comment: That explains it, I'm using 1.8.7 - edited answer to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use `return` here, it causes the block to return to the iterator, the iterator to return to the enclosing method and the enclosing method to return to its caller. Use `next` instead which only causes the block to return to the iterator (`sort!` in this case) and do something like:

```
wardList.sort! do |x,y|
  next  1 if x[:seqno].nil?
  next -1 if y[:seqno].nil?
  comp = x[:seqno] <=> y[:seqno]
  comp.zero? ? x[:name] <=> y[:name] : comp
end
```

Comment: This gives the wrong result if `x[:seqno].nil? && !y[:seqno].nil?`